# Facebook login OK but cannot connect to app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook JavaScript SDK.

When I click the Facebook Share button on my web page, the Facebook Login window pops up.  I typed in the username and password, logged in, and the message

> "User cancelled login or did not fully authorize"

showed up.  I did log in successfully, but somehow the permissions requested are not authorized.

When I clicked the Facebook Share button again, the message

> "User is logged in to Facebook, but not connected to app"

showed up.

The Facebook app is created successfully with App ID & App Secret.  I have also entered the domain name under App Domains and my site under Website with Facebook Login.

I do not know what went wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

---

This is the Facebook Login window, but it does not ask the user to authorize permissions.

[image: Facebook Login Window]

The code is as follows:

```
<body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
               FB.init({
                    appId          : 'myAppId',
                    channelUrl     : '/www.mydomain.com/channel.html',
                    oauth          : true,
                    cookie         : true,
                    status         : false
               });

               facebookLogin();
          };

          function facebookLogin() {
               FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                         console.log('Welcome!');
                    } else {
                         console.log('User cancelled login or not fully authorized');
                    }
               },
               {scope:'email,publish_actions'});
          }

          function checkLoginStatus() {
               FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                         // Do something
                    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                         // Do something
                         console.log("User is logged in to Facebook, but not connected to app");
                    } else {
                         // Do something else
                    }
               });
          }

          (function(d, s, id) {
               var js, fjs = d.getElementByTagName(s)[0];
               if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
               }
               js = d.createElement(s);
               js.id = id;
               js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
               fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
     </script>

     .
     .
     .
</body>
```

This is the button code:

```
$('#fb-button').click(function() {
     checkLoginStatus();
}
```

Comment: You can not return a value out of FB.getLoginStatus, because that method is asynchronous – please look up what that means if you are not familiar with that concept! (And I don’t see any actual sharing code at all. To just let the user share something, you can use the feed or the share dialog – they don’t need to connect to your app for that.)

Comment: Thanks! I see. I did not know the FB code is asynchronous. I will reprogram the code.  I do have a share dialog, but did not show it here.

Comment: The Facebook Login pop up does not ask the user to authorize requested permissions is a different problem.  I have done a quick test, edited code above.  I still got the message "User cancelled login or not fully authorized" after logged in to Facebook.

Comment: Why both- login on btn click and login on load (async). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This is just a quick test to see whether Facebook login works when the web page first load.  And clicking the button will just check the login status. It will not login.

Comment: The problem is email and publish_actions permissions are not authorized.  The Facebook Login pop up window should show these permissions and ask the user to login.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to disable the Sandbox mode on the Facebook app settings. Everything works fine after the Sandbox mode is disabled.